# Customize PDFStamper using iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, itext, signing, customization, stamp

I'm using iTextSharp to sign PDFs. When signing, it stamps the document with 4 fields: who signed, when, reason and location. What I meant to do is to add a field below (or above, that doesn't matter) with custom information.

Any Idea?

Here's my code that is generating the stamp:

```
PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, memoryOut, '\0');
        PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.SignatureAppearance;

        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rectangle = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 100, 500, 200);

        sap.SetVisibleSignature(rectangle, stp.Reader.NumberOfPages, null);
        sap.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        sap.SetCrypto(null, chain, null, null);
        sap.Reason = ssReason;
        sap.Contact = ssContact;
        sap.Location = ssLocation;

        sap.Acro6Layers = true;
        //sap.SignatureGraphic = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(ssImageUrl);
        //sap.SignatureGraphic.ScaleToFit(131, 45);
        sap.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.Description;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several options:

1. modify one of the `PdfTemplate`s from `sap.getLayer(int)`.
2. call `sap.setLayer2Text()` to include your extra information.
3. Use a graphic.  You can wrap a `PdfTemplate` in an `Image`, so you can draw anything you want.  Then

   `sap.Render = PdfSignatureAppearance.SignatureRender.GraphicAndDescription`
4. Hack The Source.

Comment: I sticked to 2nd option. Easy and fits my needs :) thank you very much!

Comment: PS: I didn't know this in advance.  I discovered it in the [Java class reference](http://api.itextpdf.com/).